# Group data with row count by pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
                     open   high    low     close
date                
2017-04-10 09:01:00 3992.0  3992.0  3982.0  3984.0
2017-04-10 09:02:00 3985.0  3988.0  3980.0  3986.0
2017-04-10 09:03:00 3986.0  3986.0  3973.0  3977.0
2017-04-10 09:04:00 3977.0  3983.0  3974.0  3981.0
2017-04-10 09:05:00 3980.0  3980.0  3956.0  3961.0
2017-04-10 09:06:00 3961.0  3968.0  3959.0  3964.0
```

There is some stock data generated every minute above.
I want to group them with 15 rows for each group and then apply ohlc function to each group. Is there any good method to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried even if it's wrong ?

Comment: By 15 rows, do you mean 15 minutes? And if so, what would be the open and high? The max /min open or the first open? Same question for close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect something along the lines should work:

```
df.resample('15Min').agg({'open': 'first', 
                          'high': 'max', 
                          'low': 'min', 
                          'close': 'last'})
```

**Proof**:

```
df
                    open    high    low     close
date                
2017-04-10 09:01:00 3992.0  3992.0  3982.0  3984.0
2017-04-10 09:02:00 3985.0  3988.0  3980.0  3986.0
2017-04-10 09:03:00 3986.0  3986.0  3973.0  3977.0
2017-04-10 09:04:00 3977.0  3983.0  3974.0  3981.0
2017-04-10 09:05:00 3980.0  3980.0  3956.0  3961.0
2017-04-10 09:06:00 3961.0  3968.0  3959.0  3964.0

df.resample('2Min').agg({'open': 'first', 
                          'high': 'max', 
                          'low': 'min', 
                          'close': 'last'})

                    open    high    low     close
date                
2017-04-10 09:00:00 3992.0  3992.0  3982.0  3984.0
2017-04-10 09:02:00 3985.0  3988.0  3973.0  3977.0
2017-04-10 09:04:00 3977.0  3983.0  3956.0  3961.0
2017-04-10 09:06:00 3961.0  3968.0  3959.0  3964.0
```

Comment: You may think about upvoting and accepting the solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Sergey Bushmanov . It solved my question.
And added more for my special situation.
Since there is some time 'gap' in data, so I can't use resample directly.

I tried this base on above code. The result is good.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)  
groupby_list=list((df.index/15).map(lambda x:int(x)))
df.groupby(groupby_list).agg({
        'code':'first','date':'first', 'open': 'first', 
                          'high': 'max', 
                          'low': 'min', 
                          'close': 'last'})
```

result:

```
open    high    code    close   low date
0   3992.0  3992.0  jd1709  3916.0  3914.0  2017-04-10 09:01:00
1   3916.0  3935.0  jd1709  3920.0  3913.0  2017-04-10 09:16:00
2   3919.0  3926.0  jd1709  3921.0  3910.0  2017-04-10 09:31:00
3   3921.0  3923.0  jd1709  3920.0  3913.0  2017-04-10 09:46:00
4   3919.0  3928.0  jd1709  3927.0  3917.0  2017-04-10 10:01:00
5   3926.0  3932.0  jd1709  3927.0  3923.0  2017-04-10 10:31:00
6   3927.0  3928.0  jd1709  3915.0  3912.0  2017-04-10 10:46:00
7   3916.0  3924.0  jd1709  3918.0  3912.0  2017-04-10 11:01:00
8   3919.0  3925.0  jd1709  3916.0  3916.0  2017-04-10 11:16:00
9   3917.0  3928.0  jd1709  3924.0  3912.0  2017-04-10 13:31:00
```